# Need some help on data mining platform recommendation

Tags: data-mining, software-recommendation

Currently I need one data mining platform (or solution) meets such requirements:

### Data Source

I can import data from: CSV, MySQL, PostgreSQL, **HDFS**.

Optional: NoSQL, MongoDB.

### Interface

I can assemble models and datas with drag & drops (like Weka).

### Algorithms

I can model with common machine learning algorithms: Logistic Regression, Random Forest, SVM, word2vec, etc.

It would be awesome if it had deep learning support.

Optional: PMML

### Customization

I can implement my own algorithms (under certain standard).

Optional: I can implement my own APIs (under certain standard).

Programming language is not limited.

### Visualization

Simple visualization is okay.

### License

Commercial solution is acceptable, open-source solution would be better (I can do some tweaks in order to meet my requirement).

There are two software I've investigated: Weka and SPSS Modeler. Weka doesn't support HDFS, while SPSS Modeler doesn't support customized algorithms.

Comment: have you found anything that gets close to your requirements? Where have you looked and what data mining platforms have you already rejected?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Weka doesn't support HDFS and SPSS Modeler is hard to custom my own algorithms.

Comment: Sounds like R can everything you listed. What's one thing R can't do?

Comment: Orange, SAS Enterprise Guide and maybe alteryx would be some other options

Comment: @StudentT As far as I know, I can't D&D in R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @oW_ mentioned, [Orange](http://orange.biolab.si) seems to be a good choice.

### Data Source

Orange3-spark provides Hive/Spark support, cool!

### Interface

A little laggy, but acceptable.

### Algorithms

Full algorithm supports (based on scikit-learn). I can implement deep learning stuff myself.

### Customization

Highly supported. Widgets & addons can be [developed](http://orange-development.readthedocs.io/).

### Visualization

Not bad.

Comment: We decided to develop a new one based on Orange, thanks for the help!